# radio application on android

Tags: android, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I'm trying to build a radio application for Android. I'm an Android newbie, but familiar with Java.

Could anyone tell me the procedure for streaming audio from an internet radio station onto my Android device in detail?

Answer (score 2):

great tutorial with buffering:

http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying,fazo.I tried this out...I'm getting an Android runtime error saying - thread attach failed. I'm trying to resolve that error.In a separate effort,I tried playing MP3 and ogg archive files over the net.The MP3 works,the ogg doesn't.MediaPlayer object refuses to be created when i give a link to a .ogg file. Do i need to handle ogg files separately?